# Is it necessary to add a argument to a function with parameters in JS

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

Coming from Java and trying to learn Javascript, the following code is valid:

```
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');

function respondToTheClick(evt) {
    evt.target.textContent = 'This paragraph has been clicked!'; 
}

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;

    myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement); 
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);

myCustomDiv.addEventListener('click', respondToTheClick);
```

and the following is not and gives an error

```
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');

function respondToTheClick(evt) {
    evt.target.textContent = 'This paragraph has been clicked!';
}

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;

    myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);

myCustomDiv.addEventListener('click', respondToTheClick(event) );  //<--added event argument
```

Error produced is :

> Argument type void is not assignable to parameter type (this:HTMLDivElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[string]) => any

With Java, if a method requires an argument - it must be provided. Is this not the case with JS - if so how does this work? Or is this only the case with eventListeners?

Comment: The event listener is using a callback, it errors in the second one because your invoking the method immediately, and not when the event is fired.

Comment: What you might want is `event => respondToTheClick(event)`. This passes the event variable to your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects. You can do anything to a function that you can do to an object. This includes passing it as the argument of a function.

```
addEventListener("click", respondToTheClick)
```

… passes `respondToTheClick` as the second argument of `addEventListener`.

```
addEventListener('click', respondToTheClick(event) );
```

is equivalent to:

```
let return_value = respondToTheClick(event);
addEventListener('click', return_value);
```

The second argument of `addEventListener` needs to be a function. The return value of `respondToTheClick(event)` is not a function. That is why you get an error.

When some other code, built into the browser, and inside the `addEventListener` function calls  the function you pass to it as an argument, then **that** code will pass it an Event object as an argument.

```js
function handleEvent(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

function addEventDemo(event_type, event_handler) {
    event_handler("E is " + event_type);
}

addEventDemo("click", handleEvent);
```

---

That said, JS doesn't require you to pass arguments to a function, even if it is set up to assign them to a variable. Any you don't define get the value `undefined`.

```js
function foo(a, b, c, d) {
    console.log({ a, b, c, d });
}

foo(1, 2);
```

But while JS doesn't require it, a function can enforce things.

```js
function foo(a, b, c, d) {
    if (typeof a !== "number") throw "a is not a number";
    if (typeof b !== "number") throw "b is not a number";
    if (typeof c !== "number") throw "c is not a number";
    if (typeof d !== "number") throw "d is not a number";
    console.log({ a, b, c, d });
}

foo(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example is passing a reference to the function `respondToTheClick` to `addEventListener`. The function is not immediately executed, but rather registered (using `addEventListener`) to be executed by the browser when the event happens. This is called a [**callback function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) in javascript.

In the second example, you are invoking the function and then passing the return value of that invocation as parameter to `addEventListener`. For example, `foo(sum(1, 2))` is passing `3` to `foo`, not the function `sum` itself.

In javascript, functions are objects, you can use them exactly how you would use a regular object. They are also callable (can be invoked). In javascript, as in java, you can assign objects to different variables and that won't create a new copy of the object, but rather, it will create different variables that point to the same object. Since functions are objects in javascript, the following is valid and works as expected:

```js
function sayHi() {
  console.log("Hi");
}

// 'func' and 'sayHi' will point to the same object, the object being
// a function that prints "Hi" to the console. 
var func = sayHi;  


// although there was never a function defined called 'func', this
// will still work because of the above assignment
func();
```

Now, this is exactly what is happening in the first example in the question but instead of the function `respondToTheClick` being assigned to a variable, it is passed as a parameter to `addEventListener`. Calling the argument from `addEventListener` is similar to calling the variable `func` from the above example; it will execute the function. This is what callbacks are used for in javascript.

The closest to callbacks in java is the use of [Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) reflections, like so:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void sayHi(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hi " + name);
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get a reference to a method called 'sayHi' on the class 'SomeClass' that
        // has only one parameter of type String, we have to specify the type of
        // parameters because of method overloading (different methods can have the
        // same name in java and we distinguish between them using their parameters).
        // In javascript this can be done by a simple assignment, but again, that's javascript.
        Method theSayHiMethod = SomeClass.class.getMethod("sayHi", String.class);

        SomeClass inst = new SomeClass();

        // now we can pass the reference to 'sayHi' (or more accurately, its reflection)
        // without invoking it. Notice how 'addEventListener("click", respondToTheClick)'
        // is the same as:
        callAMethodOnObject(inst, theSayHiMethod);
    }

    public static void callAMethodOnObject(Object object, Method method) {
        // 'sayHi', 'theSayHiMethod' and 'method' are the exact same method, the latter
        // two are reflections. Invoking the reflections will execute the function
        // they reflect as if it was called directly. Since everything in java is
        // an instance of some class (there are no standalone functions), we have to
        // specify the context for the method, in this example it is 'object' which is
        // the an instance of 'SomeClass' where 'sayHi' is defined
        method.invoke(object, "World!");
    }
}
```

This is almost never used in java, because if you want a method that you want to call when something happens (like an event for example), you'd usually pass an entire object containing that method and it will be called by invoking it directly on the passed object, something like this:

```
class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
    public void onClick(Event event) {
        // ...
    }
}

// then pass it to another method like so:

ClickHandler handler = new MyClickHandler();
someObject.setClickListener(handler);

// when a click happens, the method 'onClick' of 'handler' will be called. Javascript
// has the ability to pass the function directly without the need to wrap it in an
// object first.
```